# NGRX how to handle sorting performed at the backend

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

What is the best approach to handle sorting entities performed at the backend side? Currently, my state does not recognize that something changed when I adding sorted items using adapter while items still are the same as before sorting but them position in the array has changed.

### Edited

I receive sorted elements from the backend and then adding them to my current entities, but the state does not recognize position changes while all the properties of the entities are just the same and treat it like nothing changed.

```
state{
...state
entity1: adapter.addMany(payload {
  ...state.entity1
  loaded: true
 )
}
```

I know that the problem is somewhere here 
`...state.entity1` Because I concatenate the same array as payload provide. Only the position is changed.

Currently, I make a trick and as the second argument provides the initial state

```
state{
...state
entity1: adapter.addMany(payload,               
adapter.getInitialState({
            loaded: true
  })
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've already tried to do.

Comment: Override your list with the one your backend returns?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding a sorting method to the selector function, and added a paramater in the Entity state to save the order, here is the solution i made:

**Selector:**

```
export const selectCategoriesInStore = createSelector(
    selectCategoriesState,
    categoriesState => {
        const items: CategoryModel[] = [];
        each(categoriesState.entities, element => {
            items.push(element);
        });
        const httpExtension = new HttpExtenstionsModel();
        const result: CategoryModel[] = httpExtension.sortArray(items, categoriesState.lastQuery.sortField, categoriesState.lastQuery.sortOrder);
        return new QueryResultsModel(result, categoriesState.totalCount, '');
    }
);
```

you can see here that i use the method httpExtension.sortArray() to get the results sorted.

**Reducer:(State)**

```
export interface CategoryState extends EntityState<CategoryModel> {
    listLoading: boolean;
    actionsLoading: boolean;
    totalCount: number;
    lastCreatedCategoryId: number;
    lastQuery: QueryParamsModel;
    showInitWaitingMessage: boolean;
    error: any;
    lastAction: string;
    progress: number;
}
```

I added *lastQuery* parameter so i can access the sorting parameters from the selector.

*if you are using pages don't forget to get the data sorted from the backend too.*